# Accessing div>ul>li with div class

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to figure out the way I can access elements in div using ones class.

```
<div class='hs_terms_conditions field hs-form-field>
 <label class placeholder='Enter your name'>
 </label>
 <div class='input'>
  <ul class='input-list'>
   <li class='checkbox>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

My question is how can I access `<div class='input'>` from `<div class='hs_terms_conditions field hs-form-field>` and then change `<ul>` or `<li>`.
Was thinking of using classes and doing something like this:

```
.hs_terms_conditions.input.input-list.checkbox{
          /*some style*/
}
```

I did try it but couldn't make it work.
I want to be able to change just that `<li>` or `<ul>` inside that div so it doesn't apply on all others.

Comment: Don't forget to add closing `'` to your attribute (class) values!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ">":

```
.hs_terms_conditions > .input > .input-list > .checkbox {
      /*some style*/
}
```

If you use `.class1.class2.class3` it will match an element which belongs to all the classes. You could also use `.hs_terms_conditions .input .input-list .checkbox`.

Comment: To clarify: with `>`, the `<div class="input">` must be an immediate child, with (space), it only needs to be a descendant (i.e. somewhere inside the `div.hs_terms_conditions`, possibly within another div or something).

Comment: Thanks! :) @UlrichSchwarz Good explanation.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz thank you, sir, for the extra explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can access to `.checkbox` with parent access selector :

```
.hs_terms_conditions > .input > .input-list > .checkbox{
          /*some style*/
}
```